# Hadoop Web Interface : Access Denied

Tags: hadoop

I have setup Hadoop pseudo-distributed cluster (`hadoop-2.5.1`) on a linux machine following the steps [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).

I am able to access the web interface `http://localhost:50070` if I login through root.

However, if I have logged in through any other user, I get the following error on browser :

`Access Denied : You are not allowed to access the document at location http://localhost:50070`

How to grant access to Hadoop Web Interface to other users?

Comment: Just give 755 permission to the hadoop installation and try once again. The command is 
chmod -R 755 <hadoop-x.x.x>

Comment: @AmalGJose Tried that. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial that your were using does not consider other users that may access the hadoop folder. Indeed, only the root user has the right to access the hadoop folder (which is the installation folder)

I suggest to redo the installation while taking into consideration the user that you want to create. This user will manipulate hadoop folder and installation. Please, try to follow [this tutorial](http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/installing-single-node-hadoop-2-2-0-on-ubuntu/) : In step 2, you will create the user, and in step 3, you will ssh this user and continue the installation (with that user). Be sure that this new created user has the appropriate rights for the hadoop folder and sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this command as root :

```
chown -R hadoop:root /usr/local/hadoop
```

Comment: The other user is already the owner of hadoop installation directory.

Comment: <property>

<name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
<description>
If “true”, enable permission checking in HDFS.
If “false”, permission checking is turned off,
but all other behavior is unchanged.
Switching from one parameter value to the other does not change the mode,
owner or group of files or directories.
</description>
</property>